# Gradle build failed, unity bundle build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

Im building unity bundle for google play. At the end it stops and says Gradle build failed. Unity version 2021.3.23. Here are ss of errors and settings
[image][image][image][image][image]

i tried changing settings in android resolver, preferencs, and player setting. I tried to download a custom gradle with version 6.2 and it didnt change anything.

Comment: You appear to have duplicate libraries/plugins somewhere. If you look in the editor.log file you'll find more information. I'd suggest running the resolver manually and see what it says.

Comment: seems you've added an ad libs jar twice. Have you added it as a jar and declared it in gradle? If you want help we need to see your build.gradle files

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you have duplicated classes. Find one of them and just delete it. I think you installed the UnityAds from the package manager and installed one more with the other SDK. Maybe the second one was installed as meditation or maybe you installed it from other sources. Check all Plugins/Android folders.